# Como se podría poner para que responda cuando envié varias palabras?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Que responda a esto:

```
@client.command()
async def hola, que tal(ctx):
    await ctx.send('hola, muy bien gracias')
```

En vez de:

```
@client.command()
async def hola(ctx):
    await ctx.send('hola'))
```

pasad de esto, es para que me deje publicar xD

Comment: creo que se podia especificar un alias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[on_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_message) es un evento de discord.py que registra cuando un usuario envia un mensaje. Si quieres que tu bot responda a mensajes automaticamente, esta opcion es mas preferible que usar comandos.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Si el mensaje es de un bot, no se ejecutara nada del codigo
    if message.author.bot or not message.guild:
        return

    if message.content == 'hola' or message.content == 'que tal':
        await message.channel.send('hola, muy bien gracias')
```

Comment: Por favor siempre agrega una explicacion a tu codigo, https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Post editado, gracias por la aclaracion!